# Why doesn't 0.1+0.2+0.3 equals to 0.3+0.2+0.1?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Note : I'm not asking why is 0.1 + 0.2 different from 0.3.

According to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), 0.1+0.2 does not equal to 0.3, because 0.1 and 0.2 are already rounded to different numbers before comparing, which is different from rounded number from 0.3.

But my question is, why 0.1+0.2+0.3!=0.3+0.2+0.1?

```js
console.log(0.1+0.2+0.3==0.3+0.2+0.1);
```

My assumption: inside computers, floating numbers would be rounded to a value :

0.1 is round to A

0.2 is round to B

0.3 is round to C

since rounded value is exact (can be represented by binary), so I think

A+B+C should be exactly equals to C+B+A, just like 1+2+3 exactly equals to 3+2+1. But now the result is different. What wrong with my assumption?

Comment: Because floating point math is broken. Addition is performed left-to-right. `0.1+0.2+0.3` equals `(0.1+0.2)+0.3` and `0.3+0.2+0.1` equals `(0.3+0.2)+0.1`. So, yes, this ___is___ about _" `0.1 + 0.2` being different from `0.3`"_

Comment: Accumulative rounding errors in floating point arithmetic do depend on the order of operations…

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut: Why is this not a duplicate? In essence, this is still about floating point math being broken, and it is _still_ about `0.1 + 0.2`. It's just hidden in a layer of "order of operations".

Comment: @Cerbrus, sorry , yes, you're right.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut: Then may I suggest re-closing the question?

Comment: @Cerbrus, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Because floating point math is broken.

Addition is performed left-to-right (See [#13: Addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)).

`0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3` equals `(0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3` result: `0.3000000000000001 + 0.3`
`0.3 + 0.2 + 0.1` equals `(0.3 + 0.2) + 0.1` result: `0.5 + 0.1`

So, yes, this is about `0.1 + 0.2` being different from `0.3`

```js
console.log( 0.1 + 0.2  + 0.3);
console.log((0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3);
console.log( 0.3 + 0.2  + 0.1);
console.log((0.3 + 0.2) + 0.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point addition is not associative.
Imagine an exaggerated case:

1.0 + (2.0<sup>53</sup> − 2.0<sup>53</sup>) = 1.0 + 0.0 = 1.0

(1.0 + 2.0<sup>53</sup>) − 2.0<sup>53</sup> = 2.0<sup>53</sup> − 2.0<sup>53</sup> = 0.0

This is because 1.0 + 2.0<sup>53</sup> is rounded to 2.0<sup>53</sup>, since there are only 53 bits of precision in a 64-bit double precision floating point number, and you need 54 bits to represent 1.0 + 2.0<sup>53</sup>.

Comment: `(1 + 2^54) - 2^54` returns `5` for me. Or do you mean `Math.pow(2, 54)`?

Comment: @Cerbrus: of course, the expressions I posted are not JavaScript.

Comment: Well, [they are](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR).

Comment: @Cerbrus: are you happy now?

Comment: Yeap, that's much better :D